# Why does Ecto's `cast` not convert an integer to a string?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have an Ecto schema that includes `field :owned_by_id, :string`. I declared the field a string because I need to support values like "abc123" as well as values like "123".

The [docs for cast/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast/3) say:

> The second argument is a map of params that are cast according to the type information from `data`.

In my module, I define `changeset` like:

```
def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
  cast(struct, params, [:owned_by_id])
end
```

When I do this:

```
MyModule.changeset(%MyModule{}, %{owned_by_id: 1})
```

... I would expect `cast` to turn that `owned_by_id` integer param into a string, based on the `field` declaration.

However, what I get instead is a changeset that includes

```
errors: [owned_by_id: {"is invalid", [type: :string]}]
```

I could call `Integer.to_string(1)` myself, but shouldn't `cast` handle that? Is there a way to have it handle this automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the docs do say that the params are "cast according to the type information", Ecto does not implement casting for Integer -> String. My guess would be that's because this is rarely needed while the String -> Integer conversion is useful for when the input is sent via a web form where all the fields arrive as strings.

---

You can create a custom type if you want this kind of conversion. The documentation has an example of a custom type that implements something similar: https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/d40008db48ec26967b847c3661cbc0dbaf847454/lib/ecto/type.ex#L29-L40

Your type would look something like:

```
def type, do: :string

def cast(integer) when is_integer(integer) do
  {:ok, Integer.to_string(integer)}
end
def cast(string) when is_binary(string), do: {:ok, string}
def cast(_), do: :error

...
```

<sup>Note: I wouldn't recommend doing this. In my opinion, an explicit conversion would be simpler unless you're implementing something complex like the documentation example I've linked to above.</sup>

Comment: Sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a plug and play solution, you can use this hex package that I have created. https://github.com/luizParreira/ecto_cast_to_string