# (Ecto.ChangeError) value xxx for xxx does not match type :float

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a function to add a product to the database (`product` is a `map`):

```
  @derive {Poison.Encoder, only: [:s_id, :p_id]}
  schema "product_shops" do
    field :s_id, :integer
    field :p_id, :integer
    field :not_in_shop_count, :integer
    field :price, :float
  end

  def changeset(product_shop, params \\ %{}) do
    product_shop
    |> cast(params, [:s_id, :p_id, :price, :not_in_shop_count])
    |> validate_required([:s_id, :p_id])
    |> unique_constraint(:s_id, name: :unique_product_shop)
  end

  def insert_product_shop(conn, product_id, shop_id, price) do
    IO.inspect(price, label: "price")
    changeset = Api.ProductShop.changeset(%Api.ProductShop{p_id: product_id, s_id: shop_id, not_in_shop_count: 0, price: price})
    errors = changeset.errors
    valid = changeset.valid?
    case insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, product_shop} ->
        {:ok, product_shop}
      {:error, changeset} ->
        {:error, :failure}
    end
  end
```

The IO.inspect shows:

```
price: 52
```

But I get this error:

```
(Ecto.ChangeError) value `24` for `Api.ProductShop.price` in `insert` does not match type :float
```

So price is an `int` but needs to be a `float`.

this is the log from `IO.inspect(product)`

```
%{"brand" => "if",
  "categories" => [%{"categoryId" => 1, "label" => "Meat",
     "selectedAdd" => true, "selectedSearch" => false, "value" => 1}],
  "description" => "kcjcufujdifgkv. ckcfickc", "name" => "car",
  "not_vegan_count" => 0, "number_of_votes" => 0, "price" => 24,
  "rating" => nil,
  "shop" => %{"latitude" => -37.6739483, "longitude" => 176.1662587,
    "name" => "Rebel Sport", "place_id" => "ChIJgRN1iu_bbW0Rsb-fET0z81Y"}}
```

Convert price to float attempt ([using this resource](http://learningwithjb.com/posts/convert-int-to-float-and-float-to-int-with-elixir)):

```
  def insert_product(conn, product) do
  IO.puts("the product price")
  IO.inspect(Map.fetch(product, "price"))
  %{product | "price" => "price" / 1}
  IO.puts("the product price as a float")
  IO.inspect(Map.fetch(product, "price"))
```

It logs this:

```
the product price
{:ok, 24}
```

with error:

```
** (ArithmeticError) bad argument in arithmetic expression
```

How can I get `price` in the `map` to be a `float`?

Comment: Casting int to float should work automatically with `Ecto.Changeset.cast`. Please post the implementation of `Api.Product.changeset`

Comment: In your snippet, you haven't bound the updated map back to any variable, hence you still print out an integer instead of a float.

Comment: @MikeBuhot thanks. done

Comment: Looks like `:price` is missing from the field list given to `cast`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the question stated:

```
iex(1)> map = %{"foo" => 42}
%{"foo" => 42}
iex(2)> %{map | "foo" => map["foo"] / 1}
%{"foo" => 42.0}
```

Please note, that in Elixir terms are *all immutable*, and hence even correct clause:

```
%{product | "price" => product["price"] / 1}
```

is a NOOP. The result is immediately discarded. One must rebind `product` to use it later:

```
product = %{product | "price" => product["price"] / 1}
```

---

It in general should be done with [`Ecto.Changeset.cast/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast/4), not explicitly.

If for some reason one needs to cast the value manually, [`Ecto.Type.cast/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Type.html#cast/2) comes to the rescue:

```
Ecto.Type.cast(:float, 1)
#⇒ 1.0
```

---

*Sidenote:* [`IO.inspect/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#inspect/2) accepts a second parameter `opts`:

```
IO.inspect(product, label: "the product")
```

Comment: Thanks. I have now realised that I posted the wrong function `insert_product` when I was meant to post `insert_product_shop`. I have now posted the correct changeset and function up the top of my question. `cast` is already being used. But it is not working.

Comment: Show the schema, please, it’s necessary to diagnose why `cast` is not working. For why the product has not changed, please, re-read my answer.

Comment: Just added it to the top of the question.

Comment: I have no ability to check it right now, but it sounds like [`Ecto` has issues with casting `Integer`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40613577/why-does-ectos-cast-not-convert-an-integer-to-a-string#40613821). One might implement the custom type as shown above, or just use the correct `product` update as I posted.

Comment: I used `priceFloat = price / 1 ` since `price` was no longer inside a `map` in my function at the top of the question. It is working. If at some point you happen to see why the `cast` didn't work, I'd appreciate if you'd let me know. Cheers!